# Ubuntu 11.10 on laptop random restart

Tags: 11.10, laptop, touchpad, acer, restart

Laptop info:

memory 992.6 MiB

Processor Intel core duo cpu T2350 @1.86 GHz x2

Graphics unknown (point of concern)

os type 32-bit

Acer Travel Mate 4200

~~~~~

So I updated it recently but I'm still concerned that I jumped the gun in updating to 11.10 when I should rely on 10.

I had recently updated from 10 to 11.10, complete install over on top of the old dang version cause some update messed it up.  Yet, my concern was after installing 11.10 and before updating the fresh os, it had randomly restart/reboot.  Also, one time it lost control on the touch pad randomly in use (I tried using keyboard functions to turn it back on but nothing)

One last concern is as mentioned the graphics is not recognized, no driver support atm.

Currently update 11.10 and appears stable, but I'm not relying on it yet as I think I may need roll back.  Lastly, when I did a memory test overnight, I checked in the morning, it was still running and no response of any-sort to any key-presses.

With the above mentioned noticed factors any explanation?  I'm willing to provide more info, just tell me specifically what, I'm no Linux expert but I'm competent when it comes to troubleshooting.

Answer (score 1):

Could be anything from over heating to bad ram, can not tell from what you posted. Honestly I am not certain if you are using an upgrade or a fresh install.

Start with a fresh install, upgrade problem can be difficult to sort out and only cloud the picture.

Second, try booting an older kernel.

From there you would need to look though debugging

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Debugging

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/KernelDebuggingTricks

Comment: Well, I've had some version 10 for a year with no problems, but after some update version 10 was getting glitchy, asking for permissions when given and displaying programs which were not selected.   So I installed the new ubuntu version 11.10, to completely replace it, so no more older kernal at the moment.  Guess I'll have to go through debugging, my curiosity is why memory test is hanging

Comment: Outside of a hardware problem (bad ram) I've not seen memtest hang before.